# How to generate a AAR with nested dependencies

Tags: java, android, gradle, groovy, aar

I'm trying to generate an AAR of a project with the following module structure:

```
:my-library
   dependencies {
                    compile project(':my-library-core')
                }
:my-library-core
   dependencies { /* None */ }
```

My problem is that when I run the assemble task the generated AAR does include the **my-library** module classes, but it doesn't include **my-library-core** ones.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aar file **doens't contain** the transitive dependencies.

The alternative is to publish the library in a **maven repository** (public or private). Gradle in this case with the pom file is able to download also the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so there is no other "more direct" way?

Comment: In my experience there is not.

Comment: can you explain how to use the pom file ?